# Linq sort by string that is datetime

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following view model:

```
public class MvcFormsViewModel
{
    public int RecCount { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> PageOfRecords { get; set; }

    public MvcFormsViewModel()
    {
        PageOfRecords = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    }
}
```

My controller sorts the data with the following:

```
vm.PageOfRecords = vm.PageOfRecords.OrderBy(x => x.ContainsKey(sortValue) ? x[sortValue] :
                                                            string.Empty).Skip(startIndex).Take(endIndex - startIndex).ToList();
```

The sortValue is passed into the controller from the view - it will be the name of one of the columns - also a key in the dictionary.

My problem is, sometimes the value of "sortValue" param is a timestamp, in which case I would like linq to sort as datetime rather than string. How could I do this?

Comment: Converting string to `DateTime` will be most obvious way.

Comment: "re-format" the `DateTime` with `"yyyyMMddHHmmssffffff"` (`f` only if sub-seconds are needed) => automatically "correct" sorting.

Comment: Thanks but how do I reformat? I guess I have to make a change to what gets passed in to the OrderBy method but I don't know what.

Comment: No, the `OrderBy` can stay the same (you are just "selecting" the field to order by, right?). The question is, how that dictionary for the `DateTime` columns is filled (when you (hopefully) still have the actual `DateTime` values). When you store those column values, just use the given format string, and sorting should work. --- Btw. why not create an actual class for each "row" with the *correct* datatypes for each "column"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
 vm.PageOfRecords = vm.PageOfRecords
    .Skip(startIndex)
    .Take(endIndex - startIndex)
    .OrderBy(x => x.ContainsKey(sortValue) ? DateTime.Parse(x[sortValue]) : DateTime.Min).ToList();
```

But that may involve a lot of casting if the dataset is large. As someone suggested, if the data type was already DateTime this would make things easier